# How to check that laravel eloquent update method is success

Tags: laravel

I see that laravel eloquent update method returns the count of updated lines.

so if there were no line to update, it return 0 which makes it ambiguous in if statement.

so how you guys do you check if update is performed without errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referring to the Query Builder's `update` method (which returns the updated count) and not the Eloquent one (which returns a Boolean value). If that's the case, then the way to go is to use a `try ... catch` block and handle any instances of [`QueryException`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html):

```
try {
    // Get the updated rows count here. Keep in mind that zero is a
    // valid value (not failure) if there were no updates needed
    $count = DB::table('users')->update([
        'active' => true
    ]);
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    // Do whatever you need if the query failed to execute
}
```

Comment: I think it is Eloquent Model, Address::where('user_id', '=', 1)->update(['active' => false]);

when I dump(Address::where('user_id', '=', 1)) I got a Builder instance.

Comment: Well yes, because when calling static methods on a `Model` instance (such as `where`) Laravel returns a Query Builder instance, since Eloquent itself doesn't have any implementation for building queries.

Comment: What I was referring when talking about Eloquent update was if you had a saved model instance `$user = new User(); $user->active = false; $user->save();` and then you wanted to update it once more with `$user->update(['active' => true'])`; this would return a Boolean `true/false`;